# Julia ODBC connection produces pop-up in Jupyter

Tags: odbc, jupyter-notebook, julia

This is my first time using Julia and I've written a test script to connect to a database as follows:-

```
using ODBC
db = ODBC.DSN("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MyServer;DATABASE=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
```

However, when I execute the code in Jupyter, I get a pop-up each time as shown below. I would like to be able to login automatically using windows authentication and not have to manually enter the login details. Can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, which is to pass the prompt parameter as follows:

```
using ODBC
db = ODBC.DSN("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MyServer;DATABASE=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";prompt=false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shoudn't it be **True** vs Yes:

```
Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Also I think you shoud define an ODBC data source in your system and use it's name (e.g. MyDSN) in connection string:

```
db = ODBC.DSN("DSN=MyDSN;DATABASE=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
```

Comment: Both seem to produce the same result. And in both cases a pop-up is produced.

Comment: Setting DSN is not a requirement. My problem is about using windows authentication to prevent the pop-up.

Comment: understood, sorry I cant test my recommendations right now